Cantonese film: boy running away from home
I'm trying to find a movie I saw almost a couple of decades ago. My memory of it is pretty poor but there are a few things I remember:

I watched it 15-20 years ago, so its older than that, but not sure by how much
Colour film
Cantonese film
Young boy (< 10 years old) running away from home
There was a scene with the boy walking along a riverbed or stream, surrounded by trees. There may have been a small stone/wood bridge. I think someone was calling out to him
He may have been wearing a small (maybe blue?) backpack in the scene

The most important point is walking along some water as its the scene that sticks out the most when I try to remember it
I know its not much to go on, but any thoughts on what the movie might be?

That might be: Wait 'Til You're Older (2005) ?

Chan Chi-kwong (Howard Sit) is a young boy who lives with his father
  (Felix Wong) and stepmother (Karen Mok). He blames his stepmother for
  the suicide of his mother 3 years earlier and continually runs away
  from home. One day, while walking to school, he meets an eccentric old
  man (Feng Xiaogang) in the park who accidentally pours a magic potion
  he has created down a drain. The next day, a huge tree has grown from
  a seedling in the drain. Kwong goes to the man's house and steals the
  potion, falling and breaking it as he tries to run away. Some of the
  potion enters a cut in his hand, and the next day he wakes up to find
  he has grown to the age of 20 overnight. Kwong (Andy Lau) is thrilled
  that he has become an adult and is able to finally run away from home
  without being recognized. As he gets older each day, he learns more
  about being an adult and about the situations of those around him.

Movie poster, boy has blue backpack:

Movie Language: Cantonese | Mandarin
Movie trailer:




Dont think this is the film. It seems too magical, whereas the one I'm describing was very grounded in reality

@Simon: ok, but your original question does not say that it was (or was not) "grounded in reality". Are you sure? I could not find a full length movie on YouTube, as the ones that did exist were taken down for copyright matters. So, it may be difficult to find the exact scene that you mention.
